# My code will only match value and replace adjacent values when I use two InputBoxes

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I am trying to find and match a value in a second sheet, once found, I would like to replace the adjacent values that are located next to the matched value.

I want this to be done with only one InputBox. I managed to piece together the following code, which works for me, but it requires that I find the matching value on my own on the second sheet. I tried to manipulate it to automatically find the second value, however I am having trouble doing that.

Here are example values for

```
ReplaceRng (sheet1) : https://imgur.com/d59NDg5

Name = RandomName
Value1 = 27
Value2 = 29
Value3 = 31

InputRng (sheet2) : https://imgur.com/iiSTtrw

ReplaceRng Name = RandomName
ReplaceRng Value1 = 25
ReplaceRng Value2 = 22
ReplaceRng Value3 = 25
```

**So if I use this code, I can find and replace the values, but it requires two Input boxes:**

```
Sub ReplaceRange 
Dim rng As Range  
Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range 
xTitleId = "ReplaceRange"
```

'This part is where I put in the input

```
Set InputRng = Application.Selection 
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId,    
InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

'This is where the InputRng is assigned a variable name for each value in the range

```
For Each rowInputRng In InputRng.Rows
Dim Name As String, Value1 As Integer, Value2 As Integer, Value3 As Integer
Name = InputRng.Cells(1).Value
Value1 = InputRng.Cells(2).Value
Value2 = InputRng.Cells(3).Value
Value3 = InputRng.Cells(4).Value
```

'If the first cell in the Replace range is the same as in the input range, then the adjacent cells are replaced

```
For Each Row In ReplaceRngRng.Rows
If Row.Cells(1).Value = Name Then
Row.Cells(2).Value = Value1
Row.Cells(3).Value = Value2
Row.Cells(4).Value = Value3

End If
Next Row  
Next rowInputRng  
End Sub
```

**My current code looks like this, or at least what I changed from the code found above, however it doesn't seem to work and I currently cannot think of a way to change. I have tried it in several different ways, but I just can't seem to automate finding the second range:**

'Finding the value

```
xTitleId = "RangeValueReplace"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId,       
InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set ReplaceRng =     
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("InputRng.Cells(1).Value", 
"Sheet1!A1:A1000", 1, 0))
```

'Replacing adjacent cells

```
For Each Row In ReplaceRng.Rows
If ReplaceRng.Cell(1).Value = Name Then
ReplaceRng.Cells(1).Offset(, 1).Value = Value1
ReplaceRng.Cells(1).Offset(, 2).Value = Value2
ReplaceRng.Cells(1).Offset(, 3).Value = Value3
End If
Next Row
```

For most errors I get "syntax error" or Run time error '1004' Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Comment: Would help if you paste the whole code and if you paste at least a print screen of a sample data

Comment: Ok, I will soon, however I do not have enough reputation points to upload an image. I can send the url from imgur I suppose? Thanks for the very quick reply!

Comment: Sure, do that. Someone will paste it

Comment: Added examples of the data, as I do not have the full data set on me, however the full data is basically the same thing only more examples. Also, this is basically all of the code that there is. For now, all I need is to be able replace one row with another, if the condition is met. I have other parts of code that are irrelevant to this code, but will play a role in the larger macro. I am plan on posting another question in regards to that code, as I had it working, but somehow managed to overwrite the solution :(.

Comment: p.s. the images have been posted

Answer (score 0):

When using "ReplacingRng.Cells(1)" How about using this format... Cells(Row, Column). Example...

```
For Each Row In ReplaceRng.Rows
    If ReplacingRng.Cell(row,1).Value = Name Then
        ReplacingRng.Cells(row,2).value = ValueWhatever
    End if
Next
```

Comment: Looks nice, how would Dim Row, so that it reflects the rows in a certain range? I was planning on changing  Set ReplaceRng = Range("Sheet1!A1:D1000).

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finding a solution to my problem. Note that what ActiveCell you are using is important.

```
Sub Findreplace()

Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range

            xTitleId = "Findandreplace"

            Set InputRng = Application.Selection

            Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, 
            InputRng.Address, Type:=8)


            vFind = ActiveCell


            On Error Resume Next

                    With Sheet1

             Set rFound = .UsedRange.Find(What:=vFind, After:=.Cells(1, 1), 
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
                                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

                        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then

                    Application.Goto rFound, True

             End If

             End With


            Set ReplaceRng = rFound

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False


            Dim Name As String, Value1 As Integer, Value2 As Integer, Value3 As 
    Integer

                Name = InputRng.Cells(1).Value

                Value1 = InputRng.Cells(2).Value

                Value2 = InputRng.Cells(3).Value

                Value3 = InputRng.Cells(4).Value

                Value4 = InputRng.Cells(5).Value



            If ReplaceRng.Value = Name Then

                ReplaceRng.Offset(, 1).Value = Value1

                ReplaceRng.Offset(, 2).Value = Value2

                ReplaceRng.Offset(, 3).Value = Value3

                ReplaceRng.Offset(, 4).Value = Value4

            End If


End Sub
```